# Default selected simple product in configurable product

Tags: product, configurable-product, default

I have a configurable product with simple products in it(associated products). By default
when you view the configurable product magento has not set any associated products as standard, so a price of $0 is shown.

To get rid of the $0 price, i thought about if it's possible to set a default/auto choosed associated product in a configurable product? Or just tell magento to automaticly always select the lowest priced associated product?

I have tried to do a jquery trick by autoselect the second option, but then the price is not updating automaticly anymore :/

Any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't get what is a `standard` associated product. Do you mean that everytime you access the tab Associated products there are none displayed even after you create a few ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's showing $0, then for starters, you must have it setup incorrectly.

For example, let's say I'm selling a t-shirt. It's base price is $20, so that's what I use for the price of the configurable product. But for the XL version, the price is $25, so you should use $5 as the price variation.

If it shows a price of $0, then you must have set the price of the configurable products as $0.

If this doesn't suit your requirements, I can personally recommend Amasty's Pre Select extension, which will automatically select the specified option on the page load.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried to do a jquery trick by autoselect the second option, but then the price is not updating automaticly anymore

You should fire event change to update price. Something like this using prototype:

```
$( attributeId ).setValue( attributeValue ).triggerEvent('change');
```